# no matching function for call to ‘X::X()’

Tags: c++, inheritance, initializer-list

I have an application with base and derived class. I need to have a filed of the base class in derived one, but have some problems initializing it. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public :
    X( int x ) { }
} ;

class Y : public X
{
    X x ;
    Y* y ;
    Y( int a ) : x( a ) { }
} ;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And the errors:

```
/tmp/test.cpp||In constructor ‘Y::Y(int)’:|
/tmp/test.cpp|14|error: no matching function for call to ‘X::X()’|
/tmp/test.cpp|14|note: candidates are:|
/tmp/test.cpp|7|note: X::X(int)|
/tmp/test.cpp|7|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
/tmp/test.cpp|4|note: X::X(const X&)|
/tmp/test.cpp|4|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error is you are not constructing the `X` part of `Y`.  Since `Y` inherits from `X` you need to construct the `X` part of `Y`.  Since you did not the compiler does it for you.  When it does this it uses the default constructor, which `X` does not have, thus you get the error.  You need to have something like

```
Y( int a ) : X(some_value), x( a ) { }
```

To construct the `X` part of `Y` and the `x` member of `Y`.  Or you could add a default constructor for X and let it get default constructed.

Answer (score 8):

You need to call the superclass constructor, because a default constructor is not available:

```
Y( int a ) : X(some_int_like_maybe_a), x( a ) { }
```

Also consider marking `X::X(int)` as `explicit`.